# When you link a script, is it automatically run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The reason I am asking this is because in one of my pages I link a javascript script and then when I try to run a function in the javascript file, it doesn't work.

This is weird because when I copy the exact same code from the script file and put it between the   tags, the function then works fine.

Here is how I linked it:

```
<script src="../scripts/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is how it is referenced:

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="login()">log in </button></td>
```

Here is the javascript file in case you want to see it:

```
function login()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    username = encodeURICompenent(document.getElementById("username").value);
    password = encodeURICompenent(document.getElementById("password").value); 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Is `login.js` found at ../scripts/login.js?

Comment: Look in your browser console.

Comment: shit, I need to change the link of test.php ohhh i should take this down thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If you attach an external JavaScript file to your document and it contains code that were not found inside any method written on function declaration syntax. those code would execute right after the browser parses the JavaScript file.

Ex.

```
 function CallMe() {
   console.log("I'm going to execute once callMe method is invoke");
 }

 console.log("I'm going to execute once browser parses the javascript file");
```

The login method on your case wont execute unless there is an event that triggers/invokes the click event of your button.